# What action to elasticsearch index will cause the old index data not work and need reindex?

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't find info in the ES official document. I google the question and get some conclusion that may not correct. The action as below will cause old index data not to work and need to reindex.

- change the type of doc field
- rename the doc's field name
- change index setting like shard number and replica number
- change the analyzer of the doc field

There are many actions that we can do to the index. Like add a field, add analyzer, and another mapping parameter. Are there any authority document can tell me what action cause old index data not work and need reindex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a really good question and I agree that there is no proper official documentation explaining all the use-cases where certain actions will require re-indexing the data or create a new index, partly maybe as some of these are obvious and common and some are due to the lack of good documentation and have answer on different forums like Stackoverflow, [elastic discuss forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/) etc.

Anyway Let me try to add explanation to your conclusion which is correct in most of the cases you listed:

1. change the type of doc field

Yes, as Elasticsearch index/store different types of fields in different manner, this is requires like `keyword` fields doesn't go through analysis process while `text` fields passed through the standard analyzer. Think of it as [DDL of RDBMS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-ddl-dml-tcl-dcl/)

2. rename the doc's field name

Again, you are changing the field name, hence index needs to be rebuild to reflect the changes, otherwise your index and search requests won't work, this is again data definition type of change.

3. Change index settings like shard and replica number

**This is not completely correct, shards are of two types(primary shards and replica shard) and changing primary shard requires building a new index while replicas shards can be changed(both increase/decrease) dynamically.** But if you want to change the primary shards with zero-downtime than you can do this using alias method mentioned in [this official link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/index-aliases.html) , Reason for not allowing to change the primary shard is that based on this your data is divided and stored and if you change this, you have to re-arrange the data again and change your hashing/routing mechanism to know which shard holds the data, while replicas shards are just copy which you can increase/decrease all the time.

4. change the analyzer of the doc field

Again, as analyzer controls how tokens are created for your fields, changing this means you have to reindex again to reflect the correct tokens according to your new analyzer in ES inverted index.